# I want to change the display of pages

Tags: orocommerce

I want that instead of the home page https://ibb.co/Xb6VJsy, the product page https://ibb.co/bzL0KnS is displayed, I don't know how to do this.

This is the structure of my current Bundle:

```
└── Bogota
    └── Bundle
        └── NewBundle
            ├── BogotaNewBundle.php
            └── Resources
                ├── config
                │   └── oro
                │       └── bundles.yml
                ├── public
                │   └── first_theme
                │       ├── css
                │       │   └── styles.css
                │       └── images
                │           └── cathedral-of-bogota-pngrepo-com.png
                └── views
                    └── layouts
                        └── first_theme
                            ├── config
                            │   └── assets.yml
                            └── theme.yml
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the home page within the Web Catalog Management:

- go to Marketing / Web Catalogs
- click on "Edit Content Tree" for the chosen web catalog
- And change the default content variant for the root tree node. By default, it's set to the "System Page" - "Oro Frontend Root". Set the "System Page Route" to "Oro Product Frontend Prduct Index":
  [image]

For more details on the web catalog management, see the documentation:
https://doc.oroinc.com/user/concept-guides/content-management/web-catalog/

From the code level, you can achieve the same using the data migration:
https://doc.oroinc.com/backend/entities/fixtures/#data-fixtures

Comment: Hello, I tried the configuration you are telling me.... but at the moment of saving the changes are not applied and it remains the same.